# Is an ashx handler file required for each directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, httphandler

I seem to remember issues with the ashx handler not being picked up when aspx files resided in subfolders in IIS6.
Is this the case?

I've been just playing with the [configurable solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx) which allows the handler be configured in the web.config instead of as a .ashx file, does this solve the issue? if there is one!
A simple test worked perfectly for me, a once off configuration covered the whole application, eliminating the requirement for the same .ashx in all of my clients aspx directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm mixing up HttpHandler with HttpModule.
HttpHandler works like any form, it needs to be explicitly called or else configured in the web.config.